# Feature request: show when we've already answered questions related to us

Tags: feature-request, answers

Situation: currently if you click on the "Unanswered" tab, it shows you questions with no accepted answer that you might be interested in.

Unfortunately if you were to answer a few of these, and no answer yet be accepted, and you come back a few days later, it's difficult to know which of those question you *already looked at* and answered, but the author just hasn't selected anything yet:

https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged?page=2&tab=mytags

Feature request: add some means of me knowing "you already answered that one" to it.

Comment: Now this is a power-user change.  It would most benefit the kind of people answering so much that that is an issue to them...meaning people who are contributing a lot.  I like it.  (Why has this 3-year-old feature request has not been `status-[...]` tagged, by the way?  ...just low-visibility due to low vote count?)

Comment: And sometimes it might be weeks or months, not days, so you can't expect us to remember.

Answer (score 6):

It might not be a bad idea to tint the number of answers box a new color if one of the answers is yours (red for 0 answers, green for 1+ answers, some other color if one of the 1+ answers is yours):

[image: Example of the answer box tinted blue]

Comment: sure. Anything.

Comment: @roger You don't need to accept this answer; you probably want to wait until a dev weighs in on if they're going to implement some form of your request or not